# Inline-block element shifts to bottom if previous element contains an image

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/dsUnc/

However when I replace an img tag with text - elements are positioned like expected (next to each other with the same height).

Happens on all browsers.

How to fix it?

`float: left` is not an option

HTML:

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='first'>
      <img src='https://www.google.ru/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png' height='30'>
    </div>
    <div id='second'>Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 30px;
}
#first {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
#second {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to do it without `float`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/dsUnc/4/)

```
#first {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#second {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the container with `relative position` and the div you want to position with `absolute position` with `top:0;`

http://jsfiddle.net/uqAGt/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left` or `vertical-align: top` to your child divs:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dsUnc/2/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dsUnc/5/

Comment: He mentions in the question float:left is not an option.